# unable to declare a cursor in IF and ELSE block in MySQL

Tags: mysql, cursor

I am unable to declare a cursor in `IF` and `ELSE` block in **MySQL**. I am trying following.

Please help me.

```
IF p_emp_id IS NOT NULL THEN
DECLARE cur_users CURSOR FOR
      SELECT NAME 
      FROM USERS 
      WHERE emp_id = p_emp_id;
ELSE IF 
    DECLARE cur_users CURSOR FOR
      SELECT NAME 
      FROM USERS 
      WHERE manager_ID = p_mgr_id;
END IF;
```

Comment: **Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations and after variable and condition declarations.**

Comment: I am declaring this cursor as first statement of my stored proc. even it is giving syntax error when I tried to declare a variable in IF ELSE block.              IF V_tmp = 1 THEN                                                                                       Declare v_temp1 BIGINT;                                                                                    ELSE                                                                                                          Declare v_temp1 BIGINT; END IF;

Comment: Show your full code please.

Comment: CREATE  PROCEDURE `Test`()
BEGIN
declare v_DEVICE_ID varchar(200);
declare v_tmp int(2) default 1;
IF v_tmp  = 1 then 
  
   DECLARE cur_GET_ASAP_SERVERS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT IP
    FROM CONFIG_EXTERNAL_SYSTEM
    WHERE SYSTEM_NAME = 'ASAP'
    AND ACTIVE = 'Y';
else   
  
   DECLARE cur_GET_ASAP_SERVERS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT IP
    FROM CONFIG_EXTERNAL_SYSTEM
    WHERE SYSTEM_NAME = 'TestMDBJndiName';
  
end if;     
open  cur_GET_ASAP_SERVERS;
read_loop: loop
fetch cur_GET_ASAP_SERVERS into v_DEVICE_ID;
select v_DEVICE_ID;
end loop;
close cur_GET_ASAP_SERVERS;
END

Comment: Please have a look and suggest, how to accomplish this.